# Star not displaying jquery bar rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**My code**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/jquery-bar-rating121/dist/themes/fontawesome-stars.css">

<select id="example">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script src="../../assets/jquery-bar-rating121/dist/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
```

**jquery :**

```
$('#example').barrating({
        theme: 'fontawesome-stars'
 });
```

The stars arent showing, its only showing option selection dropdown. Jquery and jquery.barrating.min.js already included, fontawesome-stars.css also already included at the top, no error. Anything wrong with the code? why arent the stars displaying?

Do I only need these 2 files jquery.barrating.min.js and  fontawesome-stars.css for this plugin to work?

Comment: Can you ensure all of your scripts are loading properly in browser? You can use developer tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you load the scripts and CSS in the following order. This is the bare minimum files needed to make it work.

> Do I only need these 2 files jquery.barrating.min.js and fontawesome-stars.css for this plugin to work?

Yes, along with it, you need to have `font-awesome.css` and `jquery.js`. Also, finally, don't forget to use the `$(function () { })` to execute the code after the `document` is `ready`.

Works for me:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#example').barrating({
    theme: 'fontawesome-stars'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/jquery.barrating.js"></script>
<link href="http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/dist/themes/fontawesome-stars.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="example">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I was missing $(function() {

Comment: @TomKur I'll add that line into my answer.